# What is the psychology of abusing the victim during burglary and robbery?

Tags: social-psychology

I've studied a physiological phenomenon where, during a burglary or robbery, the one who robs constantly abuses the victim, either verbally or physically, even though that wouldn't lead to any gain. But they do so which helps them justify the act of robbery. I'd like to know the actual name of this physiological phenomenon.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. [Not all psychological phenomena needs a specific term in psychology other than the general term already applied](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2374). Do you think there should there be a specific term other than **bullying** or **victimisation**? If so, can you please provide some insight into what makes you think that?

Comment: @ChrisRogers - seems a legitimate answer to me?